# Windows Error: Error 5, when decompiling minecraft server

Tags: java, python, environment-variables, decompiling

I want to start create mods and so on to minecraft. I am a javaprogrammer myself, so the coding shouldn't be a problem. but to start the programming I need to decompile the server file from minecraft. Everything to do so is given and explained in a txt document, but nontheless I still get an annoying error.
I have checked my pth for JDK and JRE, have the latest version of both and all.
I really hope someone can help me. Here's the traceback:

```
File "runtime\decompile.py", line 143, in <module> main()
File "runtime\decompile.py", line 143, in <module> main()
File "runtime(options.config, options.force_jad) commands = Commands(donffile)
File "C:\Program Files\Java\MCP\runtime\commands.py", line 158, in __init__ self.checkfolders()
File "C.\Program Files\Java\MCP\runtime\commands.py", line 530, in checkfolders os.makedirs(self.dirtemp)
File "os.pyc", line 157, in makedirs
WindowsError: [Error 5] Access is denied: 'temp'
```

If I run as administrator I get following msg:

```
The system cannot find the path specified.
```

You'd safe my day if you could help me with this problem.

Comment: Seems that you have no permission to create that 'temp' directory.

Comment: @stacker: how can I get it, if not by "run as administrator"? :/

Comment: Which TXT file are you referreing? Could you link it?

Comment: @rlegendi : the TXT file is called README-MCP.TXT and is provided when downloding + unpacking the MCP

Answer (score 1):

Which decompiler do you use? I'd start checking this `commands.py` line 530 for any clues what value does this `dirtemp` has. I'd recommend using the [JD decompiler](http://java.decompiler.free.fr/).

Also, I'd be surprised if Notch hadn't used any obfuscators to prevent decompiling. That means you'll get a bunch of unreadable gibberish Java sources.

Comment: I use the official decompiler provided by the ppl behind minecraft in their MCP : http://www.minecraftwiki.net/wiki/Minecraft_Coder_Pack
I have been thinking about checking the the commands.py, but aint familiar with python, so I wanted to try other possibilities before diving into unknown teritory.